# Existe-t-il un algorithme phonétique français open source ?

Tags: phonétique

Pour un projet de recherche, j'aurai besoin d'un algorithme permettant de récupérer l'écriture phonétique d'une chaîne de caractères.

Aussi, je ne sais pas vraiment si je poste sur le bon site StackExchange, même si celui-ci me semble le plus approprié.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il « suffit » de trouver un logiciel de synthèse vocale open source, par exemple [celui-là](https://sourceforge.net/projects/espeak/files/), et d'en extraire la partie conversion de texte écrit en phonèmes (*Spelling-to-phoneme data source files* pour espeak).

Comment: J'ai regardé le code source de l'outil du lien, mais comme je ne suis pas un grand fan du C++, j'ai regardé les sources d'inspiration de README, et je suis tombé sur Cicero (http://www.fluxnic.net/cicero). L'aventage de cet outil plutôt que eSpeak est que le dictionnaire utilisé est plus lisible. Je vais donc certainement utiliser celui-là après l'avoir modifié pour convenir à mes besoins si je ne trouve pas mieux entre temps. Je valide votre réponse car elle m'a guidé vers le bon dictionnaire.

Answer (score 2):

Quelque chose comme [ça](https://www.octopuce.fr/soundex-en-francais-algorithme-dextraction-de-racine-phonetique-pour-moteur-de-recherche/)? On dirait que le source en C est disponible en bas de la page.

Comment: Non, il s'agit d'un algorithme de soundex. J'en ai déjà trouvé, mais ce n'est pas suffisant pour mon projet.

Comment: Essaie sur stackoverflow, ici c'est plutôt linguistique, ancien français, littérature, et très peu d'informaticiens.

Comment: @Frank « Très peu d'informaticiens », c'est vite dit. J'aurais plutôt tendance à dire qu'ils sont sur-représentés...

Comment: @jlliagre Indeed; here's another one, albeit an amateur... :)

Comment: @jlliagre - a-t-on des données sur la profession des participants à french.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Frank Oui, la NSA sait tout sur nous ;-) De notre côté, on a les informations que veulent bien publier les membres dans leur profil s'ils le renseignent. Quand on regarde la première page des contributeurs depuis l'ouverture de FSE, il semble qu'une partie importante travaille dans l'informatique.